# Firefox 58 on Fedora 27 doesn't support audio/mpeg

Tags: linux, firefox, audio, fedora

I tried to play stream music by my Firefox 58 on Fedora 27. But it couldn't do that. And the "console" displayed this:

`Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg
play`

I have heard that Fedora started to support mp3 natively since Fedora 25. Should I install an additional package to support audio/mpeg? And what should I install?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww Ok, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed `ffmpeg` and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox dropped the gstreamer backend, and ffmpeg isn't constructed in a way that make it easy for Fedora to include. This is the bug entry about this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1512041